# Persist collection of interface using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, interface

I want to persist my litte zoo with Hibernate:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "zoo") 
public class Zoo {
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Animal> animals = new HashSet<Animal>();
}

// Just a marker interface
public interface Animal {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "dog")
public class Dog implements Animal {
    // ID and other properties
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cat")
public class Cat implements Animal {
    // ID and other properties
}
```

When I try to persist the zoo, Hibernate complains:

```
Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: blubb.Zoo.animals[blubb.Animal]
```

I know about the `targetEntity`-property of `@OneToMany` but that would mean, only Dogs OR Cats can live in my zoo.

Is there any way to persist a collection of an interface, which has several implementations, with Hibernate?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

JPA annotations are not supported on interfaces. From *Java Persistence with Hibernate* (p.210):

> Note that the JPA specification
>   doesn’t support any mapping annotation
>   on an interface! This will be resolved
>   in a future version of the
>   specification; when you read this
>   book, it will probably be possible
>   with Hibernate Annotations.

A possible solution would be to use an abstract Entity with a `TABLE_PER_CLASS` inheritance strategy (because you can't use a mapped superclass - which is not an entity - in associations). Something like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractAnimal {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Lion extends AbstractAnimal implements Animal {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Tiger extends AbstractAnimal implements Animal {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Zoo {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = AbstractAnimal.class)
    private Set<Animal> animals = new HashSet<Animal>();

    ...
}
```

But there is not much advantages in keeping the interface IMO (and actually, I think persistent classes should be concrete).

#### References

- [Annotations, inheritance and interfaces](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=941363&start=0)
- [using MappedSuperclass in relation one to many](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1003328&start=0)
- [Polymorphic association to a MappedSuperclass throws exception](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/EJB-199)

Comment: Truth is, my real problem is a bit more complex than the question above so your answer doesn't work in my case. But it looks like a correct answer to my question so I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why the abstract class `AbstractAnimal` doesn't implement the interface `Animal`?

Comment: @Pascal, I tried this but then seems to require a table for AbstractAnimal table, which is not ideal but I can live with it. However after the Animal insert happens, the Animal needs a reference to a zoo and that fails because the update goes against AbstractAnimal rather than the concrete animal.

Answer (score 1):

I can guess that what you want is mapping of inheritance tree.
@Inheritance annotation is the way to go. 
I don't know if it will work with interfaces, but it will definitely work with abstract classes.

Comment: I'll try that and if it doesn't work I'll go for abstract classes.

Comment: Yep, abstract class is a better solution. As Péter Török has already said, you can put the id and other common properties to the Animal class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to annotate the interface too with `@Entity` and we have to annotate `@Transient` on all getters and setters of interface.