# Can I use @MappedSuperclass annotation on an interface?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mappedsuperclass

I want to group common mappings in an `interface`, but I cannot use an `abstract superclass` because my entities already extend another `class`. So I need an interface like below:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public interface NamedEntity {
    @Column(name = "name")
    String getName();
    void setName(String name);
}
```

and I want to use it like below:

```
public class Person {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    public Long getId(){ return id; }
    public void setId(Long id){ this.id = id; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name){ this.name = name; }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person_entity")
public class PersonEntity extends Person implements NamedEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Override
    public Long getId() { return super.getId() }
}
```

Would this work, I mean;

1. Can I use @MappedSuperclass annotation on an interface?
2. Does Hibernate have support for interfaces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. As stated [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Interfaces):

JPA has no direct support for interfaces or variable relationships.

Comment: Thank you. Another question: Does Hibernate have support for interfaces?

Comment: I'm not too familiar myself with ibernate. Perhaps [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912988/persist-collection-of-interface-using-hibernate) tells you what you need to know?

Comment: small addition .... In JPA your target is to save something (i.e. entities) ... thus this thing to save should be persistable (i.e. has state) , mapped super class is just a common part of your entity that can be shared among other entities so the same rule applies .... interface is not something to hold a 'state' , it's rather a definition for behavior