# Enforcing inclusion of fields in JPA @Entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have multiple classes annotated with `@Entity`. Half of the classes have these 3 additional fields in them: `specialFieldA`, `specialFieldB`, and `specialFieldC`; the other half do not.

Is there a JPA way to ensure that future classes have these 3 fields in them? I.e. if a teammate wants to make another class with `specialFieldA`, `specialFieldB`, and `specialFieldC` in them, is there a way to enforce having these 3 fields?

I thought of using an interface, but it didn't seem like the right strategy since you can only define methods.

I can't use an abstract class because these classes already extend a parent class.

Comment: What about an abstract class?

Comment: These classes already extend other classes. Edited my question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045027/can-i-use-mappedsuperclass-annotation-on-an-interface

Comment: You might need to reconsider the classes hierarchy design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a separate class with just those special fields in it and annotated the class with `@Embeddable`. Then in my entity I included that new class as a field and put an `@Embedded` annotation on it.

Answer (score -1):

Make a abstract class like Special fields have the annotation `@MappedSuperClass`

```
@MappedSuperClass
public abstract class SpecialFields {
  @Column(name = "specialFieldA")
  private String specialFieldA;

  @Column(name = "specialFieldB")
  private String specialFieldB;

  @Column(name = "specialFieldC")
  private String specialFieldC;
}
```

All the classes furthue you want to have these fields in it extends from this class Like

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="sample")
public class Sample extends SpecialFields  implements Serializable{
     //All three fields are part of this class and automatically maps to date base columns with same name..
}
```

Now all the classes which have these three fields must extends from  SpecialFields class. and other are not.

Comment: OP already has an abstract class which is parent for these classes. He/she cannot extend both abstract classes/

Comment: Then make this class to parent of that abstract class.