# How to use abstract entity AND conditional attribute type WITH table per class in Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have read through many questions and tried to solve the following problem with Java generics and `@MappedSuperclass`. Important for me is that I have to have different tables as you would get with `TABLE_PER_CLASS`.

This is the goalI want to achieve in Spring-Boot:

[image: design of inheriting entities with seperate tables]

I am stuck because examples like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912988/persist-collection-of-interface-using-hibernate/2918468#2918468) are not representing my more complex goal from the image above.
The different inheriting classes (`ZooAnimal`, `CircusAnimal`) have attributes that must not be null AND must not be used in the respective opposite class.

E.g. an object of ZooAnimal may have

```java
@NotNull
int numberOfZoosSeen;
```

and an object of CircusAnimal may have

```
@NotNull
boolean hasEatenClown;
```

That's why they need their own database tables.

Is it technically possible and if no, is there a better design that ensures that the entities `Zoo`, `Circus`, `ZooAnimal` and `CircusAnimal` have their own tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Animal` and `Institution` are abstract, I would question the need to declare any association mappings in them directly.

You could simply use the following approach:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Institution {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    public abstract List<? extends Animal> getAnimals();

    ...
}

@Entity
public class Zoo extends Institution {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "institution")
    private List<ZooAnimal> animals;

    public List<ZooAnimal> getAnimals() { //covariant type
        return animals;
    }

}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Animal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    public abstract Institution getInstitution();

    ...
}

@Entity
public class ZooAnimal extends Animal {

    @ManyToOne
    private Zoo institution;

    public Zoo getInstitution() { //covariant type
        return institution;
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect the answer to be that easy. Thank you!

Comment: Since I am not yet too familiar with generics, how would you define a setter for `Animal` and `Institution`?

Comment: Just define regular setters in subclasses. Or, if you really insist on setters in the superclass, you could declare `Animal` as `public class Animal<T extends Institution>` and use `abstract <T> void setInstitution(T institution)` as well as `abstract <T> T getInstitution()`

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to implement these classes using `TABLE_PER_CLASS` strategy with generics, but you have to use `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` annotation instead of `@MappedSuperClass`.
To know more about `TABLE_PER_CLASS` strategy visit [jpa advanced mappings](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_advanced_mappings.htm)

To prepare your abstract classes using generics all you have to do is understand the relation between classes before using generics. After that you have to understand `recursive generics` concept to implement your case using generics.
For more information's visit [introduction to generics](https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-generics-java-%E2%80%93-0)

Here is the implementation of classes:-

**Institution class**

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Institution<T extends Institution<T, S>, S extends Animal<S, T>> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    //add properties, constructors and methods

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Animal.class, mappedBy = "institution",  cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<S> animals;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<S> getAnimals() {
        return animals;
    }

    public void setAnimals(List<S> animals) {
        this.animals = animals;
    }
}
```

**Animal class**

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Animal<T extends Animal<T, S>, S extends Institution<S, T>> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    //add properties, constructors and methods

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Institution.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private S institution;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public S getInstitution() {
        return institution;
    }

    public void setInstitution(S institution) {
        this.institution = institution;
    }
}
```

**Important Note:-** During implementing the entities using generics you must specify the `targetEntity` class in `@OneToOne`, `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne` and `@ManyToMany` annotations as shown in the above code because JPA cannot detect the target entity in generics.

**Zoo and ZooAnimal classes**

```java
@Entity
public class Zoo extends Institution<Zoo, ZooAnimal> {

    //add properties, constructors and methods
}

@Entity
public class ZooAnimal extends Animal<ZooAnimal, Zoo> {

    //add properties, constructors and methods
}
```

**Circus And CircusAnimal**

```java
@Entity
public class Circus extends Institution<Circus, CircusAnimal> {

    //add properties, constructors and methods
}

@Entity
public class CircusAnimal extends Animal<CircusAnimal, Circus> {

    //add properties, constructors and methods
}
```

As you can see in the implementation of subclasses, there is no need to override `getAnimals()` and `getInstitution()` methods to change their return types because we already specified its return types using generics.

Comment: Your answer contains a lot of helpful information. Thank you!